# Ajax get/load succeeding but returning no data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using the following function to try and pull in the html for a given page:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://admin.alex/college/current'",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(response){
        data = response;
        console.log('Success: ' + data);
    },
    error: function(e){
        console.log('Fail: ' + e);
    }
});
```

This function always succeeds but only logs "Success: ", 'data' is always blank. I have tested by pointing to `url: "http://admin.alex/'",` and the full html is pulled in as expected.

I have tried using the newer syntax and get the same results with:

```
$.ajax('http://admin.alex/college/current')
     .done(function(html){
         console.log('Sucess: ' + html);
     })
     .fail(function(e){
     console.log('Fail: ' + e);
});
```

This is the complete html for the page I am targeting:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
5361
</body>
</html>
```

The "5361" is inserted via a php echo. If I create a fatal error right after the echo on that page, my ajax function will pull in the html from between the body tags containing the fatal error message. Note that on other pages it pulls in the complete html from opening to closing html tags.

Comment: You're being blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). In which case you'll need to use a server-side proxy to make the request for you.

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools to monitor the request, see EXACTLY what data you're getting.

Comment: I don't think I'm being blocked by Same Origin Policy as I'm running the Ajax method from a different page on the same site. The Ajax method returns properly for many other pages on this site just not this one for some reason

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem in the "http://admin.alex/college/current" link. First try to open that link directly in the browser which should return json data. If it does not return json response then first change that and then try to get the response from that page.

Thanks
Nisarg

Comment: no, you don't necessarily need json responses for ajax calls. you can respond with html, xml, text.. and so on.

Comment: Yes I agree. I just used it as an example. However, if you try to open that URL, there is no page in that.

Comment: i never tried it - i was thinking that it's just some example url.

Comment: That site is on a personal VM. I think the issue is with the Ajax call returning before the page is fully loaded. The content is put there via a php echo call.